# Insert if not exists, if exists update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm getting usersfrom this API.

https://redmine-mock-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users

There are 100 in total (100 different ids). I added them to my mongodb database using mongoose but the problem is that it's always adding (i already have 5000 users (50 times repeated 100 users)

I want to add if the `id` does not exist or update if it exists.

What am I doing wrong? `users` is the array of users from the API

```
 db.collection("users").insertMany(users, function (error, response) {
                        if (error) throw error;
                        console.log("Number of users inserted: " + response.insertedCount);
                        db.close();
                    });
```

Comment: I think you just need to know the terminology for a successful web search here.  The notion of _insert or update_ is referred to as __upsert__.  You can set the `upsert` flag on the update.  Try searching for `mongodb upsert`.

Answer (score 3):

try following format

```
db.collection.update({'_id': Id}, //Find with the unique identifier
                     {//put whatever you want to insert},
                     {upsert: true}
                    )
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Id is not defined

Comment: Please add your query here

Comment: which query? I just get the users array from the webservice and insert them with the code i have above. Nothing else

Comment: Hi John, what is your unique identifier column, add it instead of _id

Comment: It's the `Id` that gives error. please check the API. I want to insert that users in my mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [mongo db docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) it looks like `insertMany` is not what you want to use here. You probably want to use `updateMany` as it supports `upserts` where `insertMany` doesn't.

You should be able to use something like this:

```
db.collection("users").updateMany(
   {},
   users,
   {
     upsert: true
   }
)
```

This is using an empty filter so will insert if the item doesn't exist or update if it does.

Comment: MongoError: the update operation document must contain atomic operators.

Comment: Can you add an example of what your user data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>
   }
)
```

The updateMany() method takes the following parameters:

---

Filter
The selection criteria for the update. The same query selectors as in the find() method are available.

- Specify an empty document { } to update all documents in the collection.

Update
The modifications to apply.

- Use Update Operators such as $set, $unset, or $rename.

Upsert
Optional. When true, updateMany() either:

Creates a new document if no documents match the filter. For more details see upsert behavior.
Updates documents that match the filter.
To avoid multiple upserts, ensure that the filter fields are uniquely indexed.

Defaults to false.

```
db.users.updateMany(
       {},
       {$set: users},
       {
         upsert: true
       }
    )
```